# Handling notification going to the app

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have a notification on my notification bar that redirects to my app. Here's how I do it.

```
private void sendNotificationToDevice(String message)
 {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = message;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Landstar";
        CharSequence contentText = message;
        Intent intent= new Intent(context, Login.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        mNotificationManager.notify(1111, notification);
 }
```

I want to know where can I handle the event when the user clicks the notification on the notification bar. I do not like to handle it in onResume. I want it to be separated to it. The behavior when clicking the notification returns to my app. But not what I am expecting, I'm doing background processing when the app is in the background. So I want my app to reflect that process when I click the notification. Any ideas? THanks!

Comment: you mean your bg process is a service? please provide more info like what app must do when user clicks notification from statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

this code is put after notification send function call

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction("RECEIVED_ACTION");
broadcastIntent.putExtra("msg", message);
ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

use broadcast receiver ,you can directly go in your app.

below code is call in your acrtivity.
// A BroadcastReceiver must override the onReceive() event.
    private BroadcastReceiver gcmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
    private String broadcastMessage;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        broadcastMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("gcm");

        if (broadcastMessage != null && viewAdminLimit != null) {
            // display our received message

        }

    }
};
```

and call below method in your activity

```
public void onResume() {

        IntentFilter gcmFilter = new IntentFilter();
        gcmFilter.addAction("RECEIVED_ACTION");
        viewAdminLimit.registerReceiver(gcmReceiver, gcmFilter);

    }

public void onPause() {

        viewAdminLimit.unregisterReceiver(gcmReceiver);

    }
```

i hope this code is useful for you.